# Make/ Model/ Motorization/ Year product search opencart

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I am in the process of building an AutoParts Store using opencart. I was wondering if there was a way for the end user to search by Make Model Motorization and Year of a car, and then have the corresponding car parts be listed.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a commercial extension available for this [here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3621). In terms of doing from a standard OC install it's not going to be possible